# RStudio hangs or crashes when large file is in project path

Tags: r, file, rstudio

This question refers to using the "projects" option in `RStudio` (v. 0.99.891) with software `R` (v. 3.2.3).

When there is a large `.R` file in a project directory or in a sub-directory of a project directory, RStudio will either hang on start up or hang when accessing a sub-directory (not necessarily the sub-directory containing the large file). It may recover after a very long waiting time or crash. Usually I have to end the process using Windows system. A file size of 300 MB or more caused the problem on my machine.

The only current work around is moving the file outside of the project directory.

*Does somebody know a different fix to this problem?* Moving the file outside the project folder causes cumbersome accessibility, because the project folder is the default working directory.

System information: Win7 professional, 8 MB Ram, i7 quadro 2.2 Ghz

Comment: you're maxing out R's memory. do you have anything else loaded in your workspace or project directory thats eating up memory?

Comment: No. When I start R without the file in the project folder I have: `memory.limit()` `[1] 8105` and `memory.size()` `[1] 49.3`.

Comment: do you face the same problem in the normal r environment (i.e. outside of project mode)?

Comment: see comment below; the problem was using the `.R` format for large files instead of `.RData`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files with the R extension ar code files. Usually they can not be huge. Files with RData extension stand for R data files. These ones can be huge. The best option would be not to save them in the project directory.

And set the option not to save workspace on exit:

[image: Save workspace]

Comment: to quote the OP: 

"The only current work around is moving the file outside of the project directory.

Does somebody know a different fix to this problem? Moving the file outside the project folder causes cumbersome accessibility, because the project folder is the default working directory."

Comment: The problem was that the file contained data and was saved as `.R`. Following your remark I changed extension to `.RData`. RStudio then starts normally. However, it is not necessary to move the folder outside of the project folder anymore. So the fix here is to use `.Rdata` instead of `.R` to save large files. I was not aware of this distinction.

Comment: Yes, project folder is the default one, but it can be changed. And as I told - it is not a good practice to save data files in the project folder.

Comment: Also it is important not to save the workspace, as otherwise it crashes again on startup (as you suggest).